# I want to ONLY select the rows of an SQL table that contain a specific thing - How do I go about doing this?

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL table with 6 columns like so:

```
id    date    time    location    description    unix
```

My table is used for an event planner web app I'm trying to write.
id is just an incremented identifier 
date is just a date in this form: Mon Nov 01 2016 
location contains where the event takes place
description is what the event is

I have a unix date stamp for each date - my goal is to output ONLY the rows of the table that have the unix date stamp of the current day.

In pseudocode it would look something like this:

```
currentdate = currentunixdate()
from table select rows where unix == current
```

This is what I TRIED but there is something wrong with it...

```
$current = time();
$data = $con->query('SELECT id, date, location, description, time, unix from calendar WHERE unix LIKE '$current'');
```

EDIT: Just need to know how to select the particular rows - I have done the rest

Comment: And what is the problem? You expect that someone will code for you?

Comment: Where day == day ?

Comment: use the right datatypes, date should be date and time should be time ( if you need 2 columns). that unix timestamp thingy is useless

Comment: @M01 The point of SO is that you _show what you have tried_ and let others point out the problem with the code and/or suggest an alternative approach. As for the answer, A ツ is correct, you should use a MySQL type which allows for easy day extraction, a unix timestamp pinpoints to a second (millisecond in some languages) and will force you to search between the first and last timestamp of that day.

Comment: What database you are using?

Comment: @RogierSpieker apologies - I will post what I tried as soon as I'm back in front of my computer - I apologise again.

Comment: @u_mulder apologies - I will post what I tried as soon as I'm back in front of my computer - I apologise again.

Comment: @YourCommonSense meaning? I'm using MAMP if that helps?

Comment: @u_mulder DONE!

Comment: @RogierSpieker DONE!

Answer (score 0):

> date is just a date in this form: `Mon Nov 01 2016`

this is wrong.
it should be a `date` field, and hold a value like `2016-11-01`. Note that it should be this way. No objections. No excuses.

> I have a unix date stamp for each date

That's quite strange because there are nearly 100000 timestamps for each date. You better change this as well. But nevertheless, to convert unix timestamp you have to use `date()` function

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
```

Comment: Thanks - will have a try at this when I'm back in front of it...  only reason I did this way is because that's the why my teacher told me to do it.

Comment: Thanks very much! but how do i do the SQL bit which actually selects the rows which contain that!?

Answer (score 0):

What we are missing in the question is the structure of you table in terms of MySQL field types.

There are several ways your question can be interpreted, mostly as there is a `TIMESTAMP` field type which, from your question, you don't seem to be using.

The way I understand your question is that you have a non-time field (e.g. `VARCHAR` or `INT`) in which you store the timestamp obtained from the code.
If this is the case, then you really need to look into the [MySQL date/time fields](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) as these will provide for everything you need when it comes to dates.

The primary downside of a timestamp as string/number is that it points to a specific second (or millisecond) on the machine it was generated on. It does not contain any timezone information and more importantly it will force your query to search between *two* values (one for the start of the day and one for the end).

While this doesn't seem too hard:

```
$time  = time();  //  this is now
$day   = (60 * 60 * 24);
$begin = $time - ($time % $day);
$end   = $begin + $day;
$sql   = 'SELECT id, date, location, description, time, unix FROM calendar WHERE unix BETWEEN ' . $begin . ' AND ' . $end;
```

You will have to calculate the range every time you want to use it.

If you would make the `unix` field to a mysql `TIMESTAMP` field (which is maybe what your teacher has told you and you already have this, I don't know), it gets very easy.

You still need to convert the timestamp to a date, but that is built in to MySQL (and thus fast).

```
$time  = time();  //  this is now
$date  = date('Y-m-d', $time);
$sql   = 'SELECT id, date, location, description, time, unix FROM calendar WHERE DATE(unix)="' . $date . '"';
```

and you also get to make that overview for the entire month

```
$time  = time();  //  this is now
$year  = date('Y', $time);
$month = date('m', $time);
$sql   = 'SELECT id, date, location, description, time, unix FROM calendar WHERE YEAR(unix)="' . $year . '" AND MONTH(unix)="' . $month . '"';
```

Now, some last tips for using a database with PHP (or any language really), make sure to look into [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), as these will help you prevent SQL-injection from day one.

At the very least, if you don't get around to dive into prepared statements (which you should, as it'll make your programming life easier and safer) you can look into [`sprintf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), which will help you prevent quotation issues such as your question code.

Example

```
$sql = sprintf('SELECT id, date, location, description, time, unix FROM calendar WHERE YEAR(unix)="%s" AND MONTH(unix)="%s"', $year, $month);
```

`sprintf` is no substitute for prepared statements, and *will not* help you prevent SQL-injection.